# Merge 2 dataframes based on timestamp and date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.
The first one has date ranges and the second one has timestamps (both in ISO8601 format).

df1:

| date_start | date_end | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-23T12-59-23-100Z | 2023-10-23T19-27-15-763Z | state3 |
| 2023-10-24T08-00-00-100Z | 2023-10-24T11-00-46-331Z | state3 |

df2:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-23T17-18-56-341Z | 1500 |
| 2023-10-24T11-46-31-887Z | 4671 |

I'd like to get a filtered version of df2 so that if there exists a timestamp for which end_date >= timestamp >= start_date for at least one row of df1, current row having that timestamp will be part of the output.

desired output:

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-23T17-18-56-341Z | 1500 |

I made an algorithm that does that by iterating row by row on df2, but I hope there is a better approach. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using the `merge` function in pandas. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming df1 has columns 'start_date' and 'end_date', and df2 has 'timestamp'

merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('timestamp'), df1, left_on='timestamp', right_on='start_date')

result_df = merged_df[(merged_df['timestamp'] >= merged_df['start_date']) & (merged_df['timestamp'] <= merged_df['end_date'])]

output_df = result_df[['Image']]
```

This should give youu a filtered version of df2 based on your conditions (hopefuly)

Comment: This is most likely an AI generated answer :p. The headers don't match OP et trigger errors..

Answer (score 0):

I would use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to do the comparisons (`=>` [`and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) `<=`) *element-wise*, then keep only the timestamps that falls within at least one interval (using [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html)) :

```
import numpy as np

# check my first edit if you need to parse the datetime columns

start, end = df1["date_start"].to_numpy(), df1["date_end"].to_numpy()
timestamps = df2["timestamp"].to_numpy()[:, None]

# does the timestamp falls between at least one interval [ST, END] ?
m = np.logical_and(timestamps >= start, timestamps <= end).any(axis=1)

out = df2.loc[m]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                  timestamp  value
0  2023-10-23T17-18-56-341Z   1500

[1 rows x 2 columns]
```